# Div height stops when exceeds Browser

Tags: html, css, height

I have created a site where there is two pillars on each side of a wrapper and gotten them to fill the whole browser, except for when the content of the site exceeds the height of the browser, in which case it stops filling the whole height of the site.

http://postimg.org/image/s2jb67cqp/

```
body {
 background:red;width: 100%;height:100%;position:relative;overflow:auto;}

#pillarLeft{
 background:green;left:0px;top:0px;width:2.8%;height:100vh;z-index:-1;float:left;
 background-repeat:repeat-y;background-size:100%;overflow:auto;}

#pillarRight{
 background:green;left:0px;top:0px;width:2.8%;height:100%;float:right;z-index:-1;
 background-repeat:repeat-y;background-size:100%;overflow:auto;}

#Wrapper {
 width: 80%;heigth:100%;margin-top:5%;margin-left:7%;margin-right:7%;padding-top:1%;
 padding-bottom:20px;float:left;}
```

So fare, I've been unable to get the two divs to fill the complete page, so I am hoping to get some help since they make the site look neat.

Kind Regards
Søren

Comment: Could you able to show your code in fiddle. Show we can see your markup.

Comment: That is only natural when you set a fixed height of 100% …

Comment: Her is a rough fiddle of the settup of the site.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/6w5ngbu4/

CBroe - Okay. But shouldn't it fill the whole thing when its set to 100%?